# How to send mouseClick result to another jFrame'?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am using netbeans IDE

I faced a problem in 'How to send mouseClick result to another jFrame'?

I set `TF_appID` as public in `SearchForNewAppointment jFrame`

no mistakes but when I click the table nothing appear ?

```
        SearchForNewAppointment show = new SearchForNewAppointment();
        int row = appointment_table.getSelectedRow();
        String table_click = (appointment_table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());

        String sql = "select * from appointment where app_id = '"+table_click+"' ";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
           String add1 = rs.getString("app_id");
           show.TF_appID.setText(add1);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an event hub?

```
public interface EventHub {
    void subscribe(String eventName, EventHandler handler);
    void publish(String eventName, Object context);
}

public interface EventHandler {
    void onEvent(Object context);
}
```

The EventHub is a singleton which is injected into both frames.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    public Frame1(final EventHub hub) {
        Button button = new Button("click-me");
        button.addAddActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              // for this simple event, the context is null. In the future,
              // more complex events might need some contextual info
              hub.publish("myCustomEvent", null);
           }
        });
        super.add(button);
    }
}

public class Frame2 extends JFrame {
    public Frame2(EventHub hub) {
        hub.subscribe("myCustomEvent", new EventHandler() {
            public void onEvent(Object context) {
               System.out.println("Button was clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This means that the publish is de-coupled from the subscribe. It also means that you can have many listeners for a single event.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether your components in the second Jframe (i.e. TF_appID) is initialized at the time of you set the value to it. Make sure you initialize the second JFrame and its required components before populating dynamic values